# Installing Python3.6.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: python

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.2, on which I try to install Python 3.6.1. I have done this multiple times in the past, but for some reason I tried it 3 times since yesterday but I kept having the same error message. Here are the steps that i have taken for my installation:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.1/Python-3.6.1.tar.xz
$ tar xvf Python-3.6.1.tar.xz    
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall   
$ sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev   
$ cd Python-3.6.1
$ ./configure  
$ sudo make altinstall
```

After the last command the following message will popup at some point:

> The directory '/home/mariejosv/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
>
> The directory '/home/mariejosv/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The error message makes two good suggestions. Have you tried either of them? (It also looks like you might have forgotten to run `make` on its own. That's the step that actually builds Python.)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible this folder was created using `sudo`? I try running a quick `sudo chown -R  mariejosv /home/mariejosv/` to reset the permissions of your home directory and try again.

You must also run `make` before `make install` to build Python.

FYI, there's some PPA repos that you can add to your software sources to install Python 3.6+ without having to compile from source. 
https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/python-3.6